# ip-fwd-entry allocation fail OSPF

Tags: router, ospf, brocade

Any idea what this error means?  I can't find much on googling.  Device is a Brocade SX.  Output is from:  `show ip ospf error`

```
**** Warning! ip-fwd-entry allocation fail 3629337 times
--- The following are for debug. They may not mean error or warning. ---
no ospf route: age, #: 29836, last id = 0.0.0.0
no ospf route: ASBR itself, #: 3222536, last id = 0.0.0.0
no ospf route: adv-rtr not ASBR, #: 80, last id = 0.0.0.0
LSA discard, < min-ls-arrival, #: 4, last id = 10.1.1.2, last src = 10.1.1.2
```

Comment: Did you try to find it on the Brocade Support website? My gut feeling tells me that this is a hardware problem or software bug. I would open a support case with Brocade.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

What are your default values?

```
show default values
```

It looks like you're hitting TCAM limits